# How to create a taxonomy terms "skills" with level "low", "medium", "high"

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to create a field that allows you to add your skill from a select list, and the level of your skill.

i.e.
skill football, level medium.

I may create the taxonomy in this way
Football
-Low
-Medium
-High
and the use hierarchical taxonomy but it means that I need to add the level per each term.

Is there a way to attach a vocabulary to another vocabulary? in this way I may create a vocabulary skills with all the skills and one vocabulary level with 3 terms.
Is there a module or a better technique?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use 2 separate vocabularies for this as well.

Comment: I second @AyeshK that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that type of field configuration is possible with

http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

[image: Conditional fields]

version is -dev for D7 but works well.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how you're planning to use this in a larger context, here's what I would do:

1. Create a vocabulary (or possibly just a plain text field with a select list) for "skill"
2. Create a second field with a dropdown list for skill level (I probably wouldn't use a taxonomy for this).
3. Make the second field dependent on the first, per [this Stackoverflow question about fieldsets and conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042523/conditional-fieldgroups-fieldsets-in-drupal-7)